# How to follow a specific friend on Spotify?

Tags: facebook, spotify

It doesn't seem there is any way to search for Facebook friends on Spotify, and then follow them. The Spotify client allows you only to refresh a random list of six friends, and hope to get lucky that the friend you want to follow appears.

[image]

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to follow Facebook friends on Spotify through the web player? Through Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Spotify update makes this possible and fairly simple.

**Follow** > **Find Friends** > **Filter by Name**

[image]

This process works for the client as well as Spotify for web.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. One of my friends doesn't appear here. Need to search with spotify:serach:numeric_id

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can do this through the [web interface](https://play.spotify.com/follow) by hitting Find Friends, it then loads all your Facebook friends and allows you to search through them.

Comment: I don't see "Find Friends." Just six random Facebook friends, and a refresh button -- no way to search or browse.

Comment: Hmm, this is what I see - http://i.imgur.com/2BFefLE.png Maybe it's a A/B split update for the web interface.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm not seeing that. You get an upvote.